# Created Powershell and using Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod to schedule Power BI Refresh but throws 403 error

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am using below code. I have replaced the credentials and other GUIDs with XXXX. Please let me know if I am missing anything. The Service principal has read/write perms on Datasets, Reports and Workspaces as mentioned by my security team.

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint XXXX -ApplicationId XXXX -Tenant XXXX 

$jsonbody = '{
  "value": {
    "days": [
      "Sunday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    "times": [
      "07:00",
      "11:30",
      "16:00",
      "23:30"
    ],
    "localTimeZoneId": "UTC",
    "enabled": true
  }
}'

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/XXXX/datasets/XXXX/refreshSchedule' -Method PATCH -Body $jsonbody -ContentType application/json

Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
```

The above script throws below error

[image: Powershell Error]

[image: Perms for Service Principal]

Comment: API rights are irrelevant. The service principal must have rights on the workspace and the dataset. Who is the owner of the dataset? Currently, only the dataset owner can schedule a refresh.

Comment: I think the problem is in your URL parameter.
remove this part "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/" and check again.

Comment: Is it a classic workspace or a new modern workspace? Service principals don’t work with classic.

Comment: In Power BI admin settings did you whitelist this service principal or allow all service principals?

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. Some I tried before posting query. It's a new workspace & not the classic one. I have added the Service Principal to Workspace as Admin and confirmed it's the owner of the dataset. I have also removed the part from the link but that also didn't work. In Power BI admin settings (Admin portal > Tenant Settings > Developer Settings) I have enabled "Allow service principals to use Power BI APIs". The security team provided me a group to add in there but I found that my account wasn't added to it. I am not sure if that has some impact but checking with the security team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ticket with Microsoft product team, I was able to crack the issue.

The first issue is that the Service Principal should be "Application permissions" type and not "Delegated". The Delegated Service Principal will throw 400 error.

The second part and the main reason for 403 - Forbidden error is that I need to takeover the dataset. It means that I shouldn't just be the admin of the Workspace but I need to first [takeover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/takeoveringroup) dataset using Power BI REST API. After taking over only, I can perform other dataset related tasks with Service Principal authentication.

Overall the sequence will be

1. Takeover Dataset
2. [Bind Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/bindtogatewayingroup). (Service Principal will require access to this Data Source in the Gateway. There are many steps for this piece to work)
3. [Update Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup) (if any)
4. [Update Refresh Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updaterefreshscheduleingroup)

If anyone is trying something similar, then I have posted a blog with detailed implementation and steps including Powershell script [here](https://www.dataunlock.com.au/power-bi-rest-api-using-service-principal-part-1/).